# инициализация Linked List

Tags: c, list

Попытался создавать и заполнять значениями ноды с помощью цикла. Почему-то всегда создается на одну ноду больше с мусорынм значением. Никак не могу понять как исправить эту проблему -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* create(int number);

int main(void){
    node* list = create(5);

    for(node* ptr = list; ptr!=NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
        printf("%i\n", ptr->n);
    }


    return 0;
}

node* create(int number){
    node* list = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* ptr = list;
    //ptr->n = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i<=number; i++){
        ptr->n = i;
        ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ну рассмотрите работу вашей `create` для `number == 1` и вы сразу увидите, где создается лишний узел с мусорным значением. Что написали - то и получили.

Comment: для таких вещей, хорошо [pythontutor.com подходит](https://goo.gl/w6snGR)

Comment: я вижу что лишняя нода создается на последней итерации цикла, но не могу дойти до условия/последовательности команд, чтобы эта лишняя нода не создавалась. Надеялся на помощь в этом

Comment: Если интересно, я делал когда-то для двусвязного списка пример быстрой сортировки: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy Интерес представляет метод *prepare()* для вашего случая.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается основного вопроса: в ф-ции вы сначала выделяете память под одну ноду, а потом запускаете цикл, где выдялете память еще 5раз. Вам нужно просто заменить '<=' на '<'.

Comment: При такой организации операций внутри цикла последняя созданная нода всегда будет содержать мусор в поле `n`. Поэтому "просто заменить '<=' на '<'" - недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы настаиваете на том, чтобы создавать самую первую ноду отдельно, еще вне цикла, то реализация может быть такой

```
node* create(int number)
{
  node* list = malloc(sizeof(node));

  node* ptr = list;
  ptr->n = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= number; ++i)
  {
    ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->n = i;
  }

  ptr->next = NULL;
  return list;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что цикл начинает итерировать с `i = 2`.

Однако я не вижу причин выносить создание первой ноды из цикла. Можно все сделать одним циклом

```
node* create(int number)
{
  node* list;
  node** pnext = &list;

  for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
  {
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->n = i;

    *pnext = ptr;
    pnext = &ptr->next;
  }

  *pnext = NULL;
  return list;
}
```